# How to create new Id with help of current column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to update `ProductId` with `SKUCode` and `Id`.

In this I'm adding 1000000 in `Id` and only two digit from `skucode`:

```
SELECT 
    ProductId,
    LEFT(SKUCode,2) AS SKU,
    10000000 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id)) AS Number
FROM
    ProductMaster
```

I'm getting the result but how to update with rollback in SQL Server 2008 R2

I want to update `ProductId` with (`SKU + Number`) where `sku` is `Nvarchar` and `Number` is `Int`.

Result

[image]

Comment: What result do you want?  How is the `productid` stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend encoding the SKU code in the product id.  If a product is misclassified, then you have to change a bunch of things in the database.  That is why surrogate keys are a good idea.  You are free to make and fix mistakes in any of the real data fields.

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want using a `CTE` and update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ProductId, LEFT(SKUCode, 2) AS SKU,
             10000000 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id)) AS Number
      from ProductMaster
     )
update toupdate
    set ProductId = SKU + cast(Number as varchar(255));
```

Comment: Gordon your query works but can I use this method while INSERT

Comment: Yes.  You would use an `insert` rather than an `update`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `Number` to `NVARCHAR()` and then concat in following:

```
CAST(NUMBER as NVARCHAR(40))
```